# how to make main thread wait for another one to finish in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, jedis

I have come up with following thread 'halo' to make it connect to db (redis, in this case) and in the event that server fails, would wait for a second and try again. In my unit test class, method is executing, and not long after new thread starts, server will fail. But then this new thread 'halo' is immediately shut down. What am I doing wrong?

```
// almost infinitely large number of sets, interrupted by server seg-fault
    // you gotta try company methods 
    Thread halo = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int count = 0;
            while (count < Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
                if (JedisPoolFactory.getStatus()) {
                    try {
                        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                            master.set(String.format("key_%d", count), String.format("value_%d", count));
                            System.out.println(master.get(String.format("key_%d", count)));
                            count++;
                        }
                    } catch (JedisConnectionException igr) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {}
                    }
                } else {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ignrod) {}
                }
            }
        }
    });
    halo.start();

    try {
        master.debug(DebugParams.SEGFAULT());
        halo.join();
    } catch (JedisConnectionException ignored) {
    } catch (InterruptedException igr) {}
```

Comment: master is Jedis instance

Comment: [`Synchronization`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html)

Comment: please elaborate @ShreyasChavan

Comment: using halo.join() would make current thread to wait for thread halo to finish processing, no?

Comment: thread synchronization is when threads share the resources, so do you mean synchronization is for the Jedis instance master?

Comment: Does the main thread catch an JedisConnectionException or an InterruptedException when it actually runs?

Comment: actually no exception at all, the thread halo just finishes up without printing anything.

Answer (score 0):

thread joining should be done outside of exceptions, when master goes segfault it invokes jedisconnectionexception.